# How to hide an iframe using a button in the content page?

Tags: asp.net

Hai ,

I am using an iframe for showing a page in my website. i want to hide that frame using a close button in the content page( the page which is showing in the frame)

How to do this? use jQuery
[See this image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.16304cfe1b.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a client side script to make the iframe invisible. Lets consider the IFrame is inside a div `<div id="iFrameContainer"><iframe></iframe></div>`. In such a case you can fire a javascript on click of the button and set something like `document.getElementById("iFrameContainer").visible=false;` This should work for you.

Comment: Get me well, The close button in an another page, Consider
<div id="iFrameContainer"><iframe src="Page1.aspx"></iframe></div>. Close button in this page 1. And your container div in another page.
Now think.

Comment: Oh! I got it clear now. So the page inside the iframe is having the button. In such a case, you are not allowed to access anything on the parent page if the page is not the part of the same doamin. If they are in the same domain, you can access the parent doc also. Let me know whether the pages are ffrom the same domain or not.

Answer (score 0):

have your iframe in your div tag. Then execute the following statement for hiding or displaying respectively when button get onclick event.

```
 
document.getElementById('iframeid').style.display='none'; // hiding
document.getElementById('ifrmaeid').style.display='block'; // displaying
```

Answer (score 0):

As iframe is html control it will pruduce an erroe while running it at the sever...
To make the iframe hide or show at particular condition ... we can use apply simple trick.. take a div element which will wrap the iframe element.. eg

```
<div id="vidPreview" runat="server" visible="false">                       
    <iframe src="demo.aspx" width="400" height="200" frameborder="0" style= "background-color:Black;"></iframe>
</div>
```

When u want to make visible just make that div's visibility property=true

in above eg make...`vidPreview=true` whenever i want to display iframe..